# To aggregate lines on a file

Tags: awk, csv

I have a file abc.csv with data like :

`abc.csv`:

```
A B C D
a x p 1
a x p 6
b y q 5
b y q 3
a x p 2
a y q 7
```

I need to write a script with `awk` to get the output file. Could this be done with a single `awk`?

`output.csv`

```
a x p 9
b y q 8
```

Conditions:

- A B C D is the file header and only for reference.
- We need to aggregate on column A so that we have unique column A in output file.
- Aggregate only those rows which have column B & C values similar or else ignore the row like row 6 is ignored.
- Add column D values while iterating each row.

Comment: Define "similar". What to do if another `a y q 3` line is added to the end?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**`Awk`** solution:

```
awk '{ k = $1 OFS $2 OFS $3 }
     { sum[k] += $4; count[k]++ }
     END{ for (i in sum) if (count[i] > 1) print i, sum[i] }' abc.csv
```

The output:

```
a x p 9
b y q 8
```